# Potential Level 3 Communication Problems via TraceRt?

Tags: wordpress, cmd

I have waited for the past 3 days to see if these problems would fix themselves, but I'll go ahead and explain what has been happening as it appears many of you guys can actually ingest a wall of information without running away from it!

tl;dr (just incase)

I'm experiencing timeouts during my tracert to multiple websites and was wondering what the problem is. I am able to connect to the website, but randomly I get the connection error, and then it refreshes the page/connects within 5 seconds of showing the error.

That being said, here we go:

The domain that we are doing the tracert to is (www.ezkratom.com)
I have done other tests to other domains, and I will post them below.

I first noticed these problems when editing the back-end of the website as we just migrated all over information from Shopify to Wordpress/WooCommerce with a GoDaddy Wordpress Hosting package.

Anyways, we did not start noticing these problems until we came over to GoDaddy.

We called GoDaddy on Friday night, and they said they had just finished fixing Wordpress Hosting issues on their end, and that there wasn't any known problem.

So I called back early this morning, around 2:00 AM. (Sunday, 12/19/17)

The guy had me send a few copies of the tracert to him that we did to the website.

This guy did not ask me to do a tracert to any other websites, but just to this one. I didn't really think about it either because I was already falling asleep for being on hold for over an hour, haha.

Anyways, he said that from the looks of the Tracert, that it appears to be a level 3 communications issue.

He proceeded to tell me that I should call my ISP within a day or two if the problem persist, and see if they can route my connection a different way since they supposedly have an agreement with level 3 that states they are obligated to connect their customers to the internet.

Though I am "connected" to the internet, I am having connection issues very randomly through the website.

I am aware that I can connect to the website. The problem is not a constant problem. It happens to me every 30-45 minutes, either when I am going through the front end, or I am going through the back end.

It seems to happen most when I am trying to load from the back-end to the front-end (for example, by pressing "preview changes" before updating the page, or even just clicking "view site" at the top of Wordpress for those that are familiar), but we have had a few customers tell us they have received the same issue when trying to load the page.

I talked to the ISP today, and of course, after two failed transfers within the call center, they were not able to do anything about it. They said that if it was "on their end", there phones would be blowing up.

I understand it is not technically on their end, but if they have an agreement with level 3, and level 3 is messing up, then why can they not reroute my connection to a different server for the time being or a different connection through Level 3? Maybe I am thinking about this in the completely wrong way as I am not very familiar, but I had my business partner run a tracert to the same domain, and he did not experience any time out. (this is posted below, the fourth trace down)

The guy at the ISP experienced timeouts at the same hops that I did, and here they are:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>tracert www.ezkratom.com

Tracing route to ezkratom.com [198.71.233.21]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    11 ms     7 ms     4 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    18 ms    13 ms    14 ms  10.205.240.1
  3    18 ms    19 ms    12 ms  ten0-0-1-2.tamp84-ser1.bhn.net [72.31.92.12]
  4    20 ms    18 ms    17 ms  ten0-1-0-8-4.tamp20-car1.bhn.net [72.31.211.42]

  5    19 ms    20 ms    21 ms  71-44-17-115.net.bhntampa.com [71.44.17.115]
  6    26 ms    29 ms    29 ms  10.bu-ether15.tamsflde20w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [66
.109.6.96]
  7    26 ms    21 ms    15 ms  ae-9.bar1.Tampa1.Level3.net [4.68.72.205]
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9    59 ms    51 ms    47 ms  4.14.98.38
 10    44 ms    45 ms    43 ms  ip-184-168-6-81.ip.secureserver.net [184.168.6.8
1]
 11    48 ms    57 ms    48 ms  ip-184-168-6-81.ip.secureserver.net [184.168.6.8
1]
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15    49 ms    52 ms    43 ms  ip-198-71-233-21.ip.secureserver.net [198.71.233
.21]

Trace complete.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Here is another tracert to www.google.com

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [64.233.176.147]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    11 ms     7 ms     9 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    25 ms    12 ms    19 ms  10.205.240.1
  3    16 ms    16 ms    21 ms  ten0-0-1-2.tamp84-ser1.bhn.net [72.31.92.12]
  4    20 ms    21 ms    18 ms  ten0-0-0-8-5.tamp20-car1.bhn.net [72.31.211.36]

  5   140 ms    56 ms    25 ms  ten0-8-0-0.orld71-CAR1.bhn.net [71.44.1.211]
  6    22 ms    23 ms    27 ms  72-31-188-170.net.bhntampa.com [72.31.188.170]
  7    29 ms    32 ms    29 ms  10.bu-ether15.orldfljo00w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [66
.109.6.98]
  8    31 ms    39 ms    38 ms  bu-ether18.atlngamq47w-bcr01.tbone.rr.com [66.10
9.1.72]
  9    34 ms    33 ms    34 ms  205.197.180.41
 10    40 ms     *       39 ms  205.197.180.54
 11    36 ms    31 ms    37 ms  216.239.51.53
 12    39 ms    35 ms    34 ms  209.85.142.138
 13    47 ms    33 ms    33 ms  209.85.142.153
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15    47 ms    41 ms    41 ms  yw-in-f147.1e100.net [64.233.176.147]

Trace complete.
```

Typically, www.google.com gives me 8+ time out requests, and this time it only did it one time.

Here is another tracert to a website I am partnered with:

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert www.vapershero.com

Tracing route to vapershero.com [174.136.29.198]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     5 ms     4 ms     6 ms  192.168.0.1
  2    18 ms    19 ms    19 ms  10.205.240.1
  3    18 ms    20 ms    31 ms  ten0-0-1-2.tamp84-ser1.bhn.net [72.31.92.12]
  4    31 ms    29 ms    22 ms  ten0-0-0-8-5.tamp20-car1.bhn.net [72.31.211.36]

  5    31 ms    34 ms    24 ms  71-44-17-117.net.bhntampa.com [71.44.17.117]
  6    21 ms    28 ms    26 ms  10.bu-ether15.tamsflde20w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [66
.109.6.96]
  7    25 ms    19 ms    21 ms  ae-9.bar1.Tampa1.Level3.net [4.68.72.205]
  8     *     1444 ms  1729 ms  ae-8-0.ear3.Dallas1.Level3.net [4.69.210.145]
  9    43 ms    47 ms    43 ms  4.79.182.238
 10   122 ms    41 ms    41 ms  174.136.57.235
 11    41 ms    43 ms    47 ms  173.237.185.65
 12    52 ms    49 ms    58 ms  server.hostleef.com [174.136.29.198]

Trace complete.
```

And finally, here is a tracert from my business partner who lives about 45 minutes south from me. He is closer to the Tampa Bay area then I am not, but I cannot see why that would make a huge difference.

He is also using WOW (used to be called Knology or something) for his home internet, and he uses FiOS at his office. This tracert was done via WOW:

```
MacBook-Pro-210:~ user$ traceroute ezkratom.com
traceroute to ezkratom.com (198.71.233.21), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  5.487 ms  2.821 ms  4.302 ms
 2  * * *
 3  user-69-73-108-93.knology.net (69.73.108.93)  22.632 ms  22.729 ms  40.298 ms
 4  user-69-73-1-240.knology.net (69.73.1.240)  26.141 ms  22.281 ms  27.545 ms
 5  dynamic-75-76-35-33.knology.net (75.76.35.33)  22.517 ms  29.430 ms  29.968 ms
 6  user-24-214-2-221.knology.net (24.214.2.221)  37.570 ms  29.553 ms  23.668 ms
 7  user-75-76-127-175.knology.net (75.76.127.175)  29.958 ms  29.759 ms  40.223 ms
 8  user-69-73-1-165.knology.net (69.73.1.165)  49.772 ms  39.398 ms  50.663 ms
 9  dynamic-75-76-35-14.knology.net (75.76.35.14)  35.758 ms  48.323 ms  42.154 ms
10  dynamic-75-76-35-13.knology.net (75.76.35.13)  59.747 ms  46.226 ms  50.368 ms
11  eqix.dc.godaddy.com (206.126.236.43)  45.125 ms  49.554 ms  50.165 ms
12  ip-184-168-6-81.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.6.81)  49.811 ms
    ip-184-168-6-83.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.6.83)  49.884 ms
    ip-184-168-6-81.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.6.81)  49.766 ms
13  ip-184-168-6-83.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.6.83)  59.391 ms
    ip-184-168-6-81.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.6.81)  49.890 ms
    ip-184-168-6-83.ip.secureserver.net (184.168.6.83)  44.943 ms
```

Hopefully there is enough info there to decipher some type of problem, but I will try to monitor this thread as closely as possible so I can reply to anyone that has some info.

Thanks in advance as I am really trying to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: When you mentioned timeouts during "tracert to multiple websites", was that multiple websites on the same server? It _is_ normal to see gaps that say "Request timed out" in traceroute's output, if a particular router doesn't send responses -- but as long as another router or the server at the end is responding consistently, it is usually ok. Also, what is the actual error message you see when using the site itself?

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks so much for the reply.

I do not think they were on the same server as one of them was to www.google.com, the other one to the vape website was on a server known as "marketleef", and then of course the main one, www.ezkratom.com, is on a "GoDaddy Wordpress" server. As far as the actual error message, I will try to get it again as it is happen pretty frequently, but it says something a long the lines of "err connection reset", but I'll post again with the exact error shortly.

Comment: Alright, so the error says:

This site can't be reached

The connection was reset.

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET